# how can i make a button public that i form in runtime?

Tags: c#, runtime, modifier

I have formed `buttons` at runtime. I need to access the `buttons` from another `form` but i can't change the modifier to public at runtime

Could you please help me?

Comment: Change the modifier of what? A button does not have a modifier. Fields and Properties have.

Comment: You should specify the UI technology used (WinForms, WPF, WebForms, ASP MVC). When asking a question on StackOverflow, you should tell us what you have tried so far, and if possible, show us the relevant code parts.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a public list of buttons to your form (I assume winforms here):

```
public List<Button> Buttons { get; private set; }
```

In the forms constructor:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Buttons = new List<Button>();
}
```

In the method where you create the buttons at runtime:

```
var button = new Button();
button.Text = "This is a new Button";
button.Location = ...;
... configure your button here

Buttons.Add(button); // Add button to list.
Controls.Add(button);
```

In the other form

```
foreach (Button btn in formWithButtons.Buttons) {
    DoSomethingWith(btn);
}
```

Since the buttons are added dynamically it makes a lot of sense to use a dynamic data structure like a `List<T>`.